# Looking for a puzzle game for young children

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I am trying to find a game again I played as a young child. I played it roughly in 1992-1994 in Germany on Windows 3.1 from a floppy disk. I was around 4 years old.

Here is what I still remember:

- It contained a couple of simple puzzle games. Aside from one game, knowledge of numbers and letters were not necessary.
- The music in the background was Rondo Alla Turca (Türkischer Marsch) from Mozart though I might have misremembered that as I (or my mother) played Lemmings at that time too. (See comments)
- One game required the player to put together various parts of a hay wagon. One part was the wheel, two parts formed the hay, ...
- Another game was to help a frog to jump from water lily to water lily. You had to estimate the distance and enter it as a number. E.g. 1 if the leaves were right next to each other. I remember having problems estimating larger distances (> 4).
- I think there was also a shadow-matching game, but I am not sure about that.
- There was a world view in which to choose the puzzle to play. For example, the pond to play the frog game or the barn? for the hay wagon puzzle.
- I dimly remember there were two friendly-looking monsters/aliens?, whose shape resembled Mike from Monster Inc. I think it was their shape used in the shadow-matching game.

I tried googling various parts of it or looked into MS-DOS game websites, but so far, no luck. My mother cannot remember any details either. She got the disk from a colleague at work.

Comment: https://www.uvlist.net/groups/info/%E2%99%ABmozartturkishmarch

Comment: First thing that came to my mind when I heard "game" + "alla turca" was Lemmings, but it doesn't seem to be Lemmings.

Comment: I did not know that page yet. I need to search in there. I did play lemmings back then with my mother, so it is possible I misremembered it.

Comment: Sounds a bit like one of the Fun School games. I can't find an exact match, though Fun School 4 for 6-8 Year Olds comes closest so far. See https://www.mobygames.com/game/fun-school-4-for-5-to-7-year-olds and https://www.mobygames.com/game/fun-school-4-for-5-to-7-year-olds/screenshots . For other Fun School games, see the list at https://www.mobygames.com/game-group/fun-school-series

Comment: Sorry, should have been "5-7" not "6-8" - the age ranges changed after Fun School 2!

Comment: @AJM No the screenshots look differently from what I remember.  While the bright color scheme looks similar, the pond game looks different. The lily leaves were placed irregularly and the frog only appeared in this one game. The monster/aliens I remember might have been in more games, but I do not remember them very clearly. But still thank you for taking the time to comment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't see any SF or Fantasy elements here.

Comment: @Spencer - The OP did mention two friendly-looking monster/alien characters, although they said that part is only dimly remembered.

Comment: @Libranova This would probably better be suited in Arqade: https://gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Shade: They only allow identification questions if you have artifacts, like screenshots.

Comment: @Shade: I did actually write the post for Arqade first, but then saw in the tag description that I need to have a screenshot or something similar. They suggested this exchange, if some fantasy element existed. I looked into other questions and saw that other puzzle games with fantasy characters (even without any story) were accepted.

Comment: I made a post about this on vcfed.org, and someone has suggested that some (not all) of the games from this floppy might have shown up again on CD-ROM (https://forum.vcfed.org/index.php?threads/a-game-identification-question-i-encountered-ms-dos-windows-3-1-floppy-disk-early-90s.1240574/). Does [this screenshot](https://forum.vcfed.org/index.php?attachments/aliens_game-jpg.1247757/) look familiar?